# OSX: modifying text selection with ⌘⇧→ and ⌘⇧←

Tags: macos, keyboard, text, text-editor, text-input

I've selected some text using my keyboard, starting at the bottom line and moving up (the **|** character indicates the cursor position):

> AAA **|{BBB CCC**
>
> **DDD}** EEE FFF

[image: create selection]

---

Now, I would like to *change the selection so that it starts at the end of the first line*, i.e. so that it looks like this:

**Expected result:**

> AAA BBB CCC **|{**
>
> **DDD}** EEE FFF

---

I can reduce the selection word-by-word with <kbd>⌥</kbd> <kbd>⇧</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd>:

[image: manipulate selection with option-shift-arrows]

---

But the natural way to do it would be via <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>⇧</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd>, to jump directly to the end of the first line. In many decent text editors this works fine (for instance Sublime Text 2). They also keep the `|` position visible when text is selected btw.

**The default behaviour of OSX apps, however, is that they ignore the fact that the cursor is currently at the start of the selection, and moving it to the right should remove the selection there.** Instead,  <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> always extends the selection from its end until the end of the line, no matter where the cursor currently is:

**Actual result:**

> AAA **{BBB CCC**
>
> **DDD EEE FFF}|**

[image: manipulate selection with command-shift-arrows]

---

Is there any way to make also native OSX apps behave the expected way?

I'm on OSX Yosemite 10.10.2 but I think this issue has been there as long as I can remember.

Comment: I can reproduce this in 10.10.1—maybe it's been fixed in the beta?

Comment: I'm on Yosemite 10.10.2 (also adding it to the question now). But I think this has always been the case. I primarily use code editors with good text editing capabilities, but I'd love to find an OS-level solution to this.

Comment: I' also updated the question with some animated gifs to make it easier to understand what the issue is.

Comment: Please have a look at [this Apple Support Document](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236) which states that cmd+shift+right arrow will `select text between the insertion point and the end of the current line`. The only line in your example, where the selection does _not already include the end of the line_, is the last line. So the _expected behaviour_ in OS X is to extend the selection from there, not to cut it short in the beginning line! I know that some Editors behave differently, but they are doing it _wrong_ not the system!

Comment: @Asmus Thank your for the link. The default OSX behaviour does indeed adhere to what is documented on that page, so it's technically the correct one. My question still stands though – is it possible to change it globally, so that it behaves like it does in more advanced editors (and on Linux and Windows for that matter)?

Comment: @Asmus There is a little asterisk after the description of that (and many other) keyboard shortcut but there's no explanation for it. Any idea what the `(*)` means?

Comment: No idea what the `(*)` means, but it's probably left over from previous versions of the documentation. I've updated my answer slightly to include the global keybinding only option I know of, but unfortunately I'm pretty sure there's no way to achieve what you're looking for. Since the behaviour is not built-in, applications would not now how to handle it even if you could trigger it.

Comment: Thanks, @Asmus. I've upvoted your answer. Will wait a bit before accepting it in case someone to come up some ingenious solution.

Comment: This trips me up everytime, too. Ignoring the implicit cursor position is very counter-intuitive. My workaround is to use ⌥ + ⇧ together with arrow keys which behaves as expected and at least is a bit faster than going character by character.

Answer (score 1):

Mac doesn't use the cursor position if you have a multiple text selection, it considers the cursor is at 'all selected text'.

You can see this demonstrated if you use  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>←</kbd>  instead of  <kbd>→</kbd> 
Adding to the selection with  <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>  includes the previous selection.

Not a fix, but a workaround might be  <kbd>→</kbd>  which would move the cursor to the end of your current selection, simultaneously deselecting it, then  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>←</kbd>   to select to the beginning of the line.

Comment: What does this mean? "A multiple text selection".

Answer (score 1):

So, the way I see it, text navigation on OS X works (and is expected to work) like this:

1. Navigate per line (or document, i.e. huge chunks of data):

   <kbd>cmd</kbd>+arrow keys : moves by lines (left/right for lines, up/down for the whole document). Hold <kbd>shift</kbd> to select
2. Navigate per word (i.e. small chunks of data):

   <kbd>alt</kbd>+arrow keys : moves by word (left/right). Hold <kbd>shift</kbd> to select.

So to achieve your "expected result" you should press the right arrow first to get it to the end of your current selection and then <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+ <kbd>←</kbd>  to select the line leading up to it.

When you already *have* a selection:

1. using the <kbd>alt</kbd> key combo's above will increase/decrease the selection based on direction (always modifying the end-point of your previous selection, presuming *that you've missed the end point slightly*). Same goes for adding single characters with shift+arrow keys only.
2. the <kbd>cmd</kbd> combo's increase in both directions, presuming you're after *selecting big chunks of text* anyway.

---

### Update

Long story short: what you want isn't really possible.
If you look at the list of available system key bindings by running

```
plutil -convert xml1 /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Resources/StandardKeyBinding.dict -o -|pl|grep -v noop:|ruby -pe '$_.gsub!(/[^ -~\n]/)' | grep -i selection
```

You'll see that even though you can bind custom keys to all selection functions 
`~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` 
there is no such function that achieves your requested behaviour (since this behaviour is not built into the system).

Comment: I think that Apple Up and Apple Down go to the beginning and end of the document, and do not navigate by page.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco you're completely right, I had written "document" just  a line before, don't know why I wrote "pages" next. Fixed it now.